# Optimal monetary model

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy

An economy is populated by identical, infinitely-lived agents (there is no population growth) that maximize the present discounted value of lifetime utility given by $$U=\sum\beta^t(ln\ c_t+Al_t)$$ where $c_t$ denotes consumption and $l_t$ - leisure. The agent divides his unit of time between time spent in work activity, $h_t$, time spent in acquiring consumption goods, $s_t$, and leisure, $l_t$, thus $$l_t=1-h_t-s_t$$ where $s_t=c_t-ln\ \frac{M_t}{p_t}$

where $M_t$ is money chosen at time t, and $P_t$ is nominal price level. At the beginning of period, agents hold money from the previous period, $M_{t−1}$, and also receive new money from the government which is distributed as a lump sum transfer. Agents produce output, $y_t$ using the following production function with labor as the only input: $$y_t=ln\ h_t$$
Output is sold and the proceeds, along with the beginning-of-period money and monetary transfer, are used to
purchase consumption and new money. The money supply is growing at the constant rate $g > 0$ implying $$\frac{M_{t+1}}{M_t}=1+g$$

I'm trying to write firstly as a dynamic programming problem but I am not sure if it's correct or not:

$${max} \sum\beta^t(ln\ c_t+Al_t)\ s.t $$
$$(1)\ l_t=1-h_t-c_t-ln\ \frac{M_t}{p_t} $$
$$(2)\ p_tc_t+p_tQ_tb_{t+1}+m_{t+1}=p_t(y-\tau_t)+m_t$$

and then just go on and do the FOCs?

Comment: Your constraint (2) is not very clear. What is $Q_t$, what is $b_{t+1}$ what is $m_t$ what is $\tau_t$. There are too many things not defined, so I don't really understand what this equation represents.  Anyways, I think the law of motion for the money supply, $M_{t+1} = (1+g) M_t$ should be added as a constraint too. Also the equation $y_t = \ln(h_t)$ is missing.